# how can I get a birth certificate

Tags: family-law, citizenship, illinois, birth-certificate

My mother abandoned me when I was 4 years old and since then I have lived in the street or in temporary shelters, I want to change my life, I have survived 43 years working honestly without vices without legal problems, I want to stop being a ghost, we live in Chicago.

How can person without a birth certificate attain one?

I have read this but it is very complex and it seems that it does not solve anything and you are stuck in the system. https://law.stackexchange.com/a/18857/21428

can not find more information related to my question, any suggestions to begin to formulate a more appropriate question on the subject?

Comment: Do you know where you were born? Do you have any identity documents?

Comment: I do not remember where I was born, I only keep a small medal with a very small inscription that says chager, it could be my last name, the memories are vague and distant at this point in my life it is already very difficult to clearly remember childhood things, this one more to say that when you have not had a happy childhood, you tend to forget everything you can to survive

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining someone else's birth certificate can be somewhere between difficult and impossible (they are not public records), but obtaining your own should be fairly easy. If you were born in Illinois, [this page](http://www.idph.state.il.us/vitalrecords/births/Pages/default.htm) tells you how. The birth certificate is not the first document that you need, though (yes, there is a catch), because you have to fill out [this form](http://www.idph.state.il.us/vitalrecords/births/Documents/birthfrm.pdf) and (as that form says) provide a current government ID such as a driver's license. If you don't happen to have an ID card, you can provide two documents with your name and at lease one must include your address. You can use one piece of USPS mail such as a bill, and then there is a list of specific documents such as insurance card, pay stub, vehicle registration, public assistance card... This explicitly excludes Social Security cards.

Comment: thank you very much, I will review this and maybe have more questions
I have a car I have the record, but it is still in the name of my ex-partner the mother of my daughter, the car I give it to me, I have a letter where the car leaves me a farewell letter, we did not know more about it

Answer (score 1):

If your income is low, you may be able to get assistance from a free or low cost legal clinic; your lawyer can order a birth certificate on your behalf. Also you can see if there is a department in the Chicago city government that will help you; an official of a municipality (City of Chicago) can order a birth certificate on your behalf.

You may be able to find information about your birth by searching newspapers of cities where you might have been born. A librarian can help with this.